# Hadoop component is not starting

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to hadoop well I've followed micheal install ( http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/ ).

When I run the command /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh, normally this will startup a Namenode, Datanode, Jobtracker and a Tasktracker on the machine.

I get only TaskTracker started here is the trace :

```
hduser@srv591 ~ $ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-srv591.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-srv591.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-srv591.out
localhost: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/namesecondary is in an inconsistent state: checkpoint directory does not exist or is not accessible.
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$CheckpointStorage.recoverCreate(SecondaryNameNode.java:729)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:208)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:150)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:676)
starting jobtracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-jobtracker-srv591.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-tasktracker-srv591.out

hduser@srv591 ~ $ /usr/local/java/bin/jps
19469 TaskTracker
19544 Jps
```

The solution of Tariq works, but still to start jobtracker and namenode here is the content of logs

```
 hduser@srv591 ~ $ cat /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-srv591.log
2013-09-21 00:30:13,765 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = srv591.sd-france.net/46.21.207.111
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_40
************************************************************/
2013-09-21 00:30:13,904 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-09-21 00:30:13,913 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-09-21 00:30:13,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-09-21 00:30:13,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-09-21 00:30:14,140 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-09-21 00:30:14,144 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-09-21 00:30:14,148 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-09-21 00:30:14,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-09-21 00:30:14,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2013-09-21 00:30:14,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-09-21 00:30:14,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 932184064
2013-09-21 00:30:14,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-09-21 00:30:14,164 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-09-21 00:30:14,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hduser
2013-09-21 00:30:14,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-09-21 00:30:14,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-09-21 00:30:14,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-09-21 00:30:14,185 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-09-21 00:30:14,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-09-21 00:30:14,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
2013-09-21 00:30:14,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-09-21 00:30:14,373 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot access storage directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name
2013-09-21 00:30:14,374 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2013-09-21 00:30:14,404 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)

2013-09-21 00:30:14,405 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at srv591.sd-france.net/46.21.207.111
************************************************************/
2013-09-21 00:31:08,869 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = srv591.sd-france.net/46.21.207.111
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_40
************************************************************/
2013-09-21 00:31:09,012 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-09-21 00:31:09,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-09-21 00:31:09,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-09-21 00:31:09,022 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-09-21 00:31:09,240 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-09-21 00:31:09,244 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-09-21 00:31:09,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-09-21 00:31:09,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-09-21 00:31:09,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2013-09-21 00:31:09,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-09-21 00:31:09,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 932184064
2013-09-21 00:31:09,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-09-21 00:31:09,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-09-21 00:31:09,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hduser
2013-09-21 00:31:09,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-09-21 00:31:09,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-09-21 00:31:09,286 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-09-21 00:31:09,286 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-09-21 00:31:09,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-09-21 00:31:09,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
2013-09-21 00:31:09,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-09-21 00:31:09,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Cannot lock storage /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name. The directory is already locked.
2013-09-21 00:31:09,501 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name. The directory is already locked.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2013-09-21 00:31:09,508 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name. The directory is already locked.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:599)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)

2013-09-21 00:31:09,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at srv591.sd-france.net/46.21.207.111
************************************************************/
```

here is log for datanode:

```
************************************************************/
2013-09-21 01:01:24,622 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = srv591.sd-france.net/46.21.207.111
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_40
************************************************************/
2013-09-21 01:01:24,855 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-09-21 01:01:24,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-09-21 01:01:24,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-09-21 01:01:24,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-09-21 01:01:25,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-09-21 01:01:25,224 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-09-21 01:01:25,499 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 1590050521; datanode namespaceID = 1863017904
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1812)

2013-09-21 01:01:25,500 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure you have created the directory **/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/namesecondary** and have proper permissions. Also, inspecting the logs(NN, DN, SNN, JT) would be helpful. If you are still facing the issue show us the logs along with the configuration files.

---

In response to your comment :

**org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.**

Looks like you haven't created any of the directories you are using in your configuration files. This exception clearly shows that. Please make sure you have created all the directories with proper permissions which you are using as values of your configuration properties.

Comment: very helpful, it is worked but now I have no namenode and no jobtracker. when I check the log I see that : 
ulimit -a for user hduser

Comment: I need the contents of log file. Whatever you have shown is **.out** file's content.

Comment: I paste the content file in my question post take a look to it

Comment: This is not the log file. See the name of the file which you have shown, it's **hadoop-hduser-namenode-srv591.out**..I need the file which end with **.log**

Comment: Great the jobtracker started miss now the namenode, please see the question for log

Comment: Datanode is still not running.

Comment: I paste them in the question

Comment: **ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID =**

Comment: This is the cause. Google it, you'll find the solution. The blog which you have followed also has some info on this

Comment: I removed /app/hadoop/tmp and I format filesystem again and it is worked thanks you

Answer (score 1):

The default Hadoop installation takes the datanode and namenode data directories as some /tmp directory on the local disk. The correct way is to manually create the data directories for datanode and namenode on local and put the path in the hdfs-site.xml. Add the following properties to /etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml and reformat the name node and restart it should be fixed.

```
<property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
 <value>file:///data/1/dfs/nn,file:///data/2/dfs/nn</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>file:///data/1/dfs/dn,file:///data/2/dfs/dn</value>
</property>
```